# Select item in hierarchical data set

Tags: usability, website-design, design-patterns, design, web

I have a set of data that the user frequently needs to select items from. The data set is very large(about 10 000 items) and is sorted in 4 levels.

What is the best way to design this for the user to get an overview and be able to select items in the last level quickly? I am considering using 4 lists next to each other, together with a search field for quick access, as seen in this image. Is there any better solution?

[image]

Comment: Categories in the second column are 1.1; 1.2; 1.3 and in the third 1.3.1; 1.3.2; 1.3.3 , right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than showing him all the different sets of categories at a time. we can show each category one at a time. and then the other set after selecting it.

- by this we can reduce active screen space and not confuse user

.
[image]

after selecting the category of the first list then those will be replaced by categories of second list and the category of list1 is shown as a button in filters row with which he can change that category of the list by clicking it and it will replace the category list with those items. like.
[image]

then this process will repeat till the last set selected.

this also has an advantage in case if his work is done with a category of list1 and he need not to bother about other lists of a category.